# gitlab issue filtering - how to OR filter rather than AND

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab issue filtering seems to default to AND filtering if you have multiple criteria against the same filter object (eg. label). For instance, if you have labels `vehicle::car`, `vehicle::truck`, `vehicle::motorcycle`, if you want to see `vehicle::car` OR `vehicle::truck`, if you put `label=vehicle::car` `label=vehicle::truck`, it will show nothing.

Is there any way to get around this this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it's not possible at the moment. In the documentation, they clearly mention "Multiple attributes are joined by a logical AND"

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#filter-issue-and-merge-request-lists

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955347/#75993116): GitLab rolled out a first implementation of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible for the moment. From their documentation on section [Filtering with multiple filters of the same type](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#filtering-with-multiple-filters-of-the-same-type):

> When you filter with these multiple filters of the same type, the AND
> logic is applied. For example, if you were filtering assignee:@sam
> assignee:@sarah, your results include only entries whereby the
> assignees are assigned to both Sam and Sarah are returned.

There are some requests for this functionality:

- [I want to filter on multiple filter labels](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/14461)
- [All filters should allow the ability to provide an OR condition](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/249576)

Some users suggested that if you add labels in the URL using a comma, e.g. &label_name=A,B it will work. However, I wasn't been able to get this working, had multiple attempts. Let me know if you you are able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab has this currently working on the issue list, for OR-filtering of Assignee, Author and Label.

See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/296031#note_1324142672.
The exact way to define the OR-filter in the user interface will possibly still evolve to become smoother.